# How to merge 2 objects into one - javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I need help with solution on this. I have two objects:
Input:

```
obj1 =  [{name:A}, {name:B}, {name:C}...,]
obj2 =  [{value:1}, {value:2}, {value:3}...,]
```

And i need to make from these 2 objects one.
Output:

```
obj3 = [{A:1}, {B:2}, {C:3}...,]
```

Anybody know how to merge obj and obj2 to one? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this

```js
const obj1 = [{name:'A'}, {name:'B'}, {name:'C'}];
const obj2 = [{value:1}, {value:2}, {value:3}];

const merged = Array.from({length:Math.min(obj1.length, obj2.length)}, (_,i) => {
  return { [obj1[i].name]: obj2[i].value };
});

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have consitent nameing, you could map with index.

```js
const
    names = [{ name: 'A' }, { name: 'B' }, { name: 'C' }],
    values = [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3 }],
    result = names.map(({ name }, i) => ({ [name]: values[i].value }));

console.log(result);
```